# Prove sample minimum and unbiased sample variance are independent

Tags: self-study, independence, sample

I have a simple random sampling (n observations) of the population $X$, whose pdf is

$$f_\theta (x) = e^{-(x-\theta)} I_{(\theta,\infty)}(x) $$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. $S^2_n$ is the unbiased sample variance.

Part of the problem asked was to prove $X_{(1)}$ is sufficient and complete, which I did. The joint pdf of $X_1, ..., X_n$ would be:
$$e^{-(\sum^n_{i=1} X_i)} e^{\theta n} I_{(-\infty, X_{(1)})}(\theta).$$
I get stuck in this part of the problem though:

**Prove $X_{(1)}$ and $S^2_n$ are independent.**

Using the independence of $\bar{X}$ and $S^2_n$ for a normal variable $X$ doesn't seem to apply, since the pdf is not of a normal function. Therefore I'm in the process of calculating the distribution of $S^2_n$ (I already have $X_{(1)}$'s) to check if the joint is the product of the marginals, but with this particular distribution it is being complicated and not very fruitful.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Perhaps you could find the conditional distribution of $S_n^2$ given $X_{(1)}=x$ and show it does not depend on $x$. Memorylessness could help

Comment: $$(X_i-\bar X)=(\{X_i-\mathbb E[X_1]\}-\{\bar X-\mathbb E[X_1]\})$$

Comment: This follows from Basu's theorem.